# Why does a VirtualNode require podSelector.matchLabels and serviceDiscovery.dns?

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-app-mesh

Why does a VirtualNode require `podSelector.matchLabels` and `serviceDiscovery.dns`?

Aren't they doing the same thing - identifying which Pods (IPs) are member of this virtual node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AWS App Mesh Controller For K8s](https://aws.github.io/aws-app-mesh-controller-for-k8s/) uses `podSelector` to match every Pod to a VirtualNode ([API Design](https://aws.github.io/aws-app-mesh-controller-for-k8s/reference/api_design/#use-selector-on-virtualnode-to-denote-node-membership)) in the Mesh as long as it does not have an `appmesh.k8s.aws/sidecarInjectorWebhook: disabled` annotation defined.